# RavenDB - Query Error

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a scenario where I am passing an xml doc into my Order Constructor and it will parse out the Order Items and then save the order to my RavenDB.  My order saves fine, but when I try to query it I get a NullRefException.  It appears to have something to do with calling my helper method that parses the OrderItems and adds them to my List that is in my Order Object.

Order:

```
   public class Order
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public int OrderTotal { get; set; }
        public List<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }

        public Order(XDocument xdoc,int orderNumber, int orderTotal)
        {
            this.OrderNumber = orderNumber;
            this.OrderTotal = orderTotal;

            GetXml(xdoc);
        }

        public void GetXml(XDocument xdoc)
        {

            List<OrderItem> orderItems = (from xml in xdoc.Descendants("OrderItem")
                                          select new OrderItem
                                          {
                                              Item = (int)xml.Element("Item"),
                                              ItemAmount = (int)xml.Element("ItemAmount")
                                          }).ToList<OrderItem>();


            OrderItem = orderItems;
        }
    }

    public class OrderItem
    {
        public int Item { get; set; }
        public int ItemAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

**Run Program (Save and Query RavenDB):**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<Orders>" +
                                  "<Order>" +
                                    "<OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>" +
                                    "<OrderTotal>20</OrderTotal>" +
                                    "<OrderItems>" +
                                        "<OrderItem><Item>1</Item><ItemAmount>5</ItemAmount></OrderItem>" +
                                        "<OrderItem><Item>2</Item><ItemAmount>15</ItemAmount></OrderItem>" +
                                    "</OrderItems>" +
                                  "</Order>" +
                                  "</Orders>");
            Order order = new Order(xdoc, 1, 20);
            SaveOrder(order);
            GetOrders();

            RavenConnection.Instance.CloseDocumentStore();
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static void SaveOrder(Order order)
        {
            using (var session = RavenConnection.Instance.GetDocumentStore().OpenSession())
            {

                session.Store(order);
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        public static void GetOrders()
        {
            using (var session = RavenConnection.Instance.GetDocumentStore().OpenSession())
            {
                var orders = session.Query<Order>().ToArray();

            }

        }

    }
```

**Error:**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is emulating a real-life application we have that is parsing xml and storing it in a DB....I was thinking of having it save to RavenDB, but this error is causing me grief.

Any suggestions...other than changing how we parse xml and load objects?

--S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am an idiot....just needed to add a base constructor to my Order....sorry everyone.